# two textplots in one plot

Tags: text, plot

I have been trying to work with textplot in R and am unsure if my question is possible or not, I know that par() can't be used to place two textplots in one plot. I have been using a page and this code to try and figure things out.

My question is: Is it possible to have two textplots within the same plot?
For example, in the par(mfrow=c(1,1)) scenario below, plot 1 is a texplot of species length. Say I wanted to replicate that textplot twice in that plot. Is that possible?

based on this site:
http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/gplots/html/textplot.html

```
textplot(version)
data(iris)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
info <- sapply( split(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species),
            function(x) round(c(Mean=mean(x), SD=sd(x), N=gdata::nobs(x)),2) )

textplot( info, valign="top"  )
title("Sepal Length by Species")
```

What I want to do is put a second textplot within that plot, underneath the original. For arguments sake, replicating that textplot twice in the plot.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've figured it out in the last four months but I thought I'd chip in an answer anyway.

The code provided is most of the way towards doing what you require already, you just have to provide some additional inputs to `title()` and/or `par()`. Namely specify that the title is to be above both of the plots by using `title("your title", outer = TRUE)` and you can further adjust the position of the title with an option in `par()`, use `par(mfrow = c(2,1), oma = c(0,0,"top",0))`. Hopefully this answers your question.

```
require('gplots')

data(iris)

info <- sapply(split(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species), 
           function(x) round(c(Mean = mean(x), SD = sd(x), N = gdata::nobs(x)),2))

## Replace top with a numerical value to control the position of the title with respect to the
## top of the page.
par(mfrow = c(2,1), oma = c(0,0, top ,0))

textplot(info, valign = "top")
textplot(info, valign = "top")

title("Sepal Length by Species", outer = TRUE)
```